# package operation fail, what can I do please?

Tags: package-management

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 346784 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace ifupdown 0.7.2ubuntu2 (using .../ifupdown_0.7.2ubuntu4_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement ifupdown ...
Preparing to replace gpgv 1.4.11-3ubuntu4.2 (using .../gpgv_1.4.11-3ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gpgv ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up gpgv (1.4.11-3ubuntu4.3) ...
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 346784 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gnupg 1.4.11-3ubuntu4.2 (using .../gnupg_1.4.11-3ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gnupg ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Setting up gnupg (1.4.11-3ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic (3.5.0-41.64) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.5.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-41-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-41-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-41-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-41-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic depends on linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-geNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
neric:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic (3.5.0-40.62) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-41-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.5.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-40-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-40-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-40-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-40-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up ifupdown (0.7.2ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic
Error in function: 
Setting up linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic (3.5.0-41.64) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.5.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-41-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-41-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-41-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-41-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-41-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic (3.5.0-40.62) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-41-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.5.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-40-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-40-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-40-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-40-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-40-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic depends on linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.5.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 1):

The disk is full. Specifically, the partition holding your kernel images (the files needed for booting the system). See here:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-41-generic with 1.
```

You need to clean out old kernel versions.

**The easy way to do this** is to install "Ubuntu Tweak" (via Software Center), click on the "Janitor" tab (the last one) and then select "System > Old kernels" in the list on the left side of the window and let it clean up.

You can also see here [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793) for an explanation how to do this manually. (Several possible ways) After you have deleted at least one old kernel version package, run `dpkg-reconfigure -a` to clean up all half installed packages.

IMHO Ubuntu should make this a little easier, but the method mentioned there works too.

If this doesn't help or you need more information, please edit your question and append the output of the following commands:

```
df
df -i
ls -la /boot
```

Comment: Please append the output of `df -i`, too